# Show nested array in consecutive lines in python

Tags: python, arrays

This is my python code:

```
d = []
for x in range(5):
d.append(["O"] * 5)
print d
```

and output is:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

but I want the output as follows:

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Eventually like this:

```
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a matrix?

Comment: You can make it simplest with numpy:

    `import numpy as np`
and   `d=np.zeros((5,5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one happens like this, if you just `print(d)` you will print the entire list but by looking at the desired output, we can tell we only want one sublist per line. So we loop through `d` and print each sublist `i` on its own line

```
d = []
for i in range(5):
    d.append(['0']*5)

for i in d:
    print(i)
```

> ```
> ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
> ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
> ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
> ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
> ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
> ```

For the second part its the same concept except we use `*` to unpack the items.

```
for i in d:
    print(*i)
```

> ```
> 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

Comment: I write this code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php
: 
d = []
for x in range(5):
    d.append(["O"] * 5)

for i in d:
    print (*i)

but i receive SyntaxError for *i

Comment: @omid it probably has to do with the online compiler